# How to Make a Synchronous Call an Asynchronous Call in Angular?

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, node.js

I have an app that shows statuses for internal processes.  It also has a separate view that allows you to set up new records.  To set up a new record, you fill out a form, and upon submit a call is made to my `nodejs` server that:

- inserts the record into a table
- kicks off a stored procedure
- routes you back to the status page

The issue here, is that the page hangs while this happens, as sometimes the stored procedure takes a minute or two to run.  So you wait for a couple minutes, and then are routed back to the status page.

Now, I don't actually care to see any exit code for this stored proc on the front end, as you will see the status of it on the status page.  I'm wondering if there's a way for me to kick this process off, but not have the front end care about the return.

I've tried adding in the `$location.path()` before the `$http` call to the server, but then the `$http` call never happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the stored procedure call in a promise.  The browser will make the call and continue on without waiting for it to complete and you can react appropriately in the resolve or reject functions.  You can use angular's $q service:

```
insertRecord();
$q(function() {
    storedProcCall();
});
redirect();
```

Comment: am I able to do this, but then not resolve nor reject?

Comment: @Jacob `resolve` & `reject` are for communicating the outcome of the promise or to properly handle an error. The above snippet will kick off the `storedProcCall()` function async and then return to the calling context, you will just never receive any communication on the outcome.